# Migration 6i to 10g Oracle reports

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oraclereports

I have problems with reports when migrating from 6i to 10g. Everything works fine except when a report is opened from another report. I am getting an error-

> REP-56107: Invalid environment id myenv for Job Type report in the command line

I only get this error when I try to open a report from another report. My Oracle version is Oracle 10.2.0.4.

Comment: I noticed that, when there is no envid in the URL, or in my enviroment I don't describe it, then everythink works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `defaultEnvId` attribute for the `environment` is set incorrectly in your `server_name.conf` file. Typically the `defaultEnvId` would look something like below-

```
<engine id="rwEng" initEngine="1" minEngine="0" maxEngine="10" engLife="50" maxIdle="30" defaultEnvId="JP"/>
```

And consecutively the definition as-

```
<environment id="JP">
  <envVariable name="NLS_LANG" value="Japanese_Japan.JA16SJIS"/>
  <envVariable name="NLS_CURRENCY" value="¥"/>
  <envVariable name="DISPLAY" value="MyServer.MyCompany.com:0.0"/>
</environment>
```

I am assuming that your file has the `defaultEnvID="myenv"` and `<environment id="myenv">`. Check this to make sure it points to the right environment. Make sure that the `defaultEnvId` in `engine`definition matches the `environment` definition. Also, keep in mind that this is an optional setting so you may or may not need this. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13597_05/bf.904/b13673/pbr_conf.htm) for details.